# How to prefetch images?

Tags: html, firefox, caching, browser-cache

I am using Firefox 40.0.3 and have some large images that I want to prefetch. Therefore, in the head section I write:

```
<head>
   .
   .
   .
   <link rel="prefetch" href="/static/CSS/images/1.png">
   <link rel="prefetch" href="/static/CSS/images/2.png">
   <link rel="prefetch" href="/static/CSS/images/3.png">
</head>
```

When I clear the cache, reload the page and then use [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/image_cache_viewer.html) to see what is cached. It seems as though the images are not cached.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using full links to the images instead?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: @jaunt, yes. And the full link does not make it prefetch.

Comment: @nlips Firefox 40.0.3

Comment: Here is my website:  http://nztracker.nz/

Comment: It appears to be working for Chrome (45) and Firefox (38), at least. When I open the page (after opening it once) it's pretty much there instantly. But when I click on 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' it takes time to load in.

Comment: Thanks @jaunt, this is because I have just fixed it and made a different solution (will post it in a few min)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, I decided to make it simple and just fetch the images, so just before the closing "body" element I have put this:

```
<div style="display:none;">

    <img src="/static/CSS/images/1.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/2.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/3.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">

</div>
```

Thus, the images will be prefetched and available for future use.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: you might have some images that are on the top of the page e.g. logo, big img on the top. For better user experience, it is important that the user will see as fast as possible without unneeded delays.
However, since it is possible that you set the logo image within the CSS, so what will happen is that 1.png 2.png and 3.png will be downloaded first and only then your logo and top image will be downloaded.

This is a bad user experience, since when he opens your webpage, there will be a delay until the 1.png 2.png 3.png are downloaded and only then your logo and the top image are downloaded. (By the way, you can use [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/image_cache_viewer.html) to see in which order the images are downloaded)

In order to prevent this delay, you can force your browser to start immediately downloading the images that you want at the top of your page (and not wait until it receives a command from the CSS to download these images).

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/logo.png"       alt=""   height="1" width="1">   <==
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/top_image.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">   <==

    <img src="/static/CSS/images/1.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/2.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">
    <img src="/static/CSS/images/3.png"  alt=""   height="1" width="1">

</div>
```